# How to prevent Rcp application from storing opened perspective state?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working on an eclipse application where i donot want the workbench state to be persisted .So i called -clearPersistedState in the ini file of my application.When it did not solve my problem then i have overridden initialize in ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor class .But still the workbench.xmi file is getting created and it is saving the state.

```
 @Override
  public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    configurer.setSaveAndRestore(false);
  }
```

ANy clue on this will be appreciated .

ini file content:

```
-clearPersistedState
-vmargs
-ea
-Xmx512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-Duser.language=en
```

Comment: -clearPersistedState does not stop the state being persisted but it does ignore that state during the startup.

Comment: @greg Yes it should ignore but in my case still it seems that it is still reading from workbench.xmi file

Comment: @greg is there any way so that my Rcp will always open with a specified perspective. Not with the perspective in which the workbench is closed

Comment: Show us you ini file.

Comment: @greg .added the init file content